# TradingView Pinescripts or Other Ways to add more Indicators Into 1?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Hello new to this community, got zero knowledge in coding. I have a free account in tradingview so I am only able to add only 3 indicators. Is there a way I can add more like 10 indicators? using pinescript or some other way if so can someone help. PS I'm broke so I just want to find a way without paying. Please Respond TYVM :)

I tried learning from you-tube but it was all errors in the pine-script and to make it difficult I did not understood a thing what I did. What I expected is, I would able to combine multiple scripts to be specific 10 open source community scripts into 1 workable and functionable indicator

BELOW ARE THE 9 DIFFERENT PINESCRIPTS I WANT TO USE AND MAKE INTO 1 FUNCTIONABLE INDICATOR

[image]

https://justpaste.it/c6y65

Answer (score 0):

If the source codes are available and they use the same `overlay` property, you can copy and merge those indicators into one script.

You can add `input.bool()` to enable/disable them individually.

You might need to be caraful with the scaling.

Comment: ill try it thanks for the time in answering it. ill ask again if i still cant make it work :)